# UWP app with restful PUT

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I am very new to C# but I need to write an UWP app to run on a Raspberry Pi with Windows 10 IoT.

I have a bluetooth dongle connected to the Pi, the app needs to send an On-Command to a Philipps Hue Ligthscrip with a restful PUT when the button is pressed.

I've tried to Google myself through Stack Overflow, Microsoft's repositories and thousands of other sites, no luck. There must be something possible with HttpClient (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient) but I could not figure out how to send PUT...

Thanks

Dominik

Comment: So what isn't working exactly? Do you have some code you've written?

Comment: Thanks @p3tch, unfortunatly not. I don't know where to start. Any hints?

Comment: Have you looked through this? https://www.developers.meethue.com/documentation/getting-started That and Microsoft's documentation on HTTPClient should be a starting point at least

Comment: Sorry, I need to send PUT instead of GET. Unfortunatly Microsoft does not describe how to use PUT...

Comment: HttpClient has `PutAsync()` which you can await, or you can build up a `HttpRequestMessage` using `HttpMethod.Put` and pass that into `HttpClient`'s `SendAsync()` method

Comment: Thank you very much, I will give it a try and come back to you! Appreciate it, @p3tch!

Comment: If you can't get it to work after trying something, update your question with the code you've tried

Answer (score 1):

In UWP in C#, you can send PUT request using httpClient.PutAsync() or httpClient.SendRequestAsync() API. The following are simple samples of using these two API to create a new device.

**Using PutAsync():**

```
        Uri requestUri = new Uri("http://sample-server-address/devices/newdevice");
        string content = @"{ deviceId:'newdevice'}";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync(requestUri, new HttpStringContent(content));
```

**Using SendRequestAsync():**

```
        Uri requestUri = new Uri("http://sample-server-address/devices/newdevice");
        string content = @"{ deviceId:'newdevice'}";

        Windows.Web.Http.HttpStringContent requestBody = new HttpStringContent(content, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8, "application/json");

        HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage();
        message.RequestUri = requestUri;
        message.Method = HttpMethod.Put;
        message.Content = requestBody;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendRequestAsync(message);
```

Reference "[UWP networking Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient)" "[HttpClient sample(UWP)](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/HttpClient)"